# Impressão com PrintDocument, PrintPreviewDialog C#

Tags: c#, impressora

Estou tentando imprimir etiquetas dos meus produtos direto do meu aplicativo.

Porém não estou conseguindo reduzir o tamanho do papel na impressão, por esse motivo estou perdendo 1 etiqueta a cada 1 impressão que faço, segue a foto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu `PreviewDialog` mostra que realmente o papel está maior que deveria: Segue a foto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não consigo ajeita-lo para impressão, alguém por favor tem uma solução?
Segue meu codigo até agora:

```
    private void btnPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DVprintPreviewDialog1.Document = DVprintDocument1;
        DVprintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();

    }

    private void DVprintDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = Properties.Resources.logo;
        Image newImage = bmp;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, 10, 3, newImage.Width, newImage.Height);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("TESTE", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(130, 13));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROBLEMA RESOLVIDO !

Apenas configurei o `Settings` na propriedade, conforme no Codigo abaixo: 
Os valores na proriedade do `PAPERSIZE`é uma conta: Todos os tamanhos são convertidos de MM para POLEGADAS e logo multiplicados por 100.

No meu caso, eu arredondei o valor, mas minha etiqueta tem 1" x 3".
Uma A4 por ex: teria ("A4", 827, 1170);

```
      DVprintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("TAM DA MINHA ETIQUETA", 300, 90);
```

Abraços